# HTTP request doesn't get Json expression with values contain a dot "."

Tags: json, perl, http, intellij-idea, dropwizard

I have a Json expression that contains values with "." and @ like this

```
     {"queued":"C1F","messageid":"dfs.jfdsf@sdf.abc.fr"}
```

that doesn't get processed by HTTP POST request , and it's give me this result :

```
    "code":400,"message":"Unable to process JSON
```

PS: my web server is created with dropWizard in Intellij IDEA

how can I resolve this problem

EDIT: this is the code used in perl

```
    my $queued=$1; my $messageid=$2 ;
    my $json= "{\"queued\":\"$queued\",\"messageid\":\"$messageid\"}";
    $req1->content($json);
    my $response=$ua->request($req1);
    if ($response->is_success) {
        my $message =$response->decoded_content ;
        print "resultat : $message \n";
    }
    else {
        print "erreur", $response->code, " ", $response->message, "\n" ;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is supposed to process your json ?

Comment: I edited the post , above with the code used, its in Perl

Comment: Do you also have the code of the request method? And the content method?

Comment: no, i dont have the request but I think its a simple HTTP POST request with content type as application/JSON

Comment: So, you don't know what happen to the Json after you send it ?

Comment: Please print the value of `$json`

Comment: User-Agent: libwww-perl/6.15..Content-Type: application/json..Content-Length: 86....{"queued":"xxxxxx","messageid":"gffgd.gfdg@g.sfds.fr"}

Answer (score 0):

It would be less error-prone to use the JSON library to build your JSON string

```
use JSON 'to_json';

my $json = to_json({ queued => $queued, messageid => $messageid });
```

Comment: i did try this , but it's keep give me the same Error, but if I change the value to a normal String without "." , its work